# Creating a Java class with a main() method which forwards the call to Scala main method

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

I created a simple Scala project in Eclipse without using Maven (or) Sbt (or) anything else. Then, i got a jar file from the project using eclipse. But, whenever i try to run a scala class which is in the jar file i get this error - `class not found` .

Comment: You can open the jar with 7hzip/WinZip and look for the main class and META-INF/MANIFEST.MF which should have a `Main-Class: ...`. Is the main class correctly written with full package path?

Comment: I have a main method in all my Scala classes. How do i specify a single class as main class ?

Comment: You need to provide the scala-library.jar in the same place as the jar. Eclipse does not pack this automatically, but you can just open the jar file with 7zip or Winrar or whatever and add it. Afterwards you need to add it as dependency in your META-INF.

Comment: To specify a mainclass, you need to edit the META-INF as well. You just have to write the line: "Main-Class: PATH_TO_YOUR_MAINCLASS". The same goes with the dependencies: "Class-Path: scala-library.jar". Note: If you store the jar in an extra folder, you need to give the path to it.